# Program not responding while querying MS Access database of 1000000 records

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2007

I am trying to search for the occurence of a string within MS Access database with 1000000 records using VB.Net. The program does not respond once it is run or it is taking a very long time. However, if I reduce the size of the database the program runs.
Below is the code Could anyone let me know how do I go about it.. Thanks in advance.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form1

    Dim rcount As Integer
    Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rcset As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sqlStr As String

    Public Sub openConn()
        Dim strConnect As String
        strConnect = "DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DefaultDir=" & Application.StartupPath & ";DBQ=atg;UID=;PWD=;"
        If conn.State = 0 Then
            conn.ConnectionString = strConnect
            conn.Open()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    End Sub

    Public Sub rcdSet(ByVal sqlStr As String)
        If conn.State = 0 Then
            Call openConn()
        End If
        If rcset.State = 1 Then
            rcset.Close()
            rcset = Nothing
            rcset = New ADODB.Recordset
            rcset.CursorLocation = ADODB.CursorLocationEnum.adUseServer
            rcset.CursorType = ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenDynamic
            rcset.LockType = ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockOptimistic
        End If
        rcset.Open(sqlStr, conn)
    End Sub

    Private Sub btn_search_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_search.Click
        Dim sql As String
        Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
        Dim rs2 As New ADODB.Recordset
        Dim res As String
        res = ""
        Call openConn()
        Dim SearchString_exist As New List(Of String)(txt_exist.Text.Split(Environment.NewLine))
        '  Dim SearchString_not_exist As New List(Of String)(txt_not_exist.Text.Split(Environment.NewLine))
        '  Do Until SearchString_exist.Count = 0
        sql = "SELECT * FROM ATG WHERE Term like '%cam%'"
        rs.Open(sql, conn, ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenDynamic, ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockOptimistic)
        While (rs.EOF <> True)
            res += rs.Fields("Term").Value + Environment.NewLine
            rs.MoveNext()
        End While
        rs.Close()
        SearchString_exist.RemoveAt(0)
        txt_exist.Lines = SearchString_exist.ToArray
        'Loop
        txt_result.Text = res
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: It will only make a small differnece but only select the one field you want, consider distinct (select Term from ATG) ... and do you need them all ? How about top 10 ?

Comment: Hey spacemonkeys.. Basically I need similar terms to be searched within those 1,000,000 records. Something like using a filter in Excel for a column full of data.

Answer (score 0):

If you're saying that the application is unresponsive once you click the button, that's because you're searching your Access database on the same thread that updates you application - that means that the application will appear busy until your database search is done (which could take a while). If you want to do this in a background thread and leave your application responsive during the search, you can do that using the threadpool:

http://www.dotnetperls.com/threadpool-vbnet

Also, the query runs better with fewer records because it has less data to search through, suggesting that it may not be indexed well. You could add an index on the "Term" field, which will help speed things up - you'd have to see if it helped. Access will have to do an index scan, not a faster index seek, so the response won't be immediate, but it will may help cut down your wait time significantly. Here's a Microsoft article that shows how to do this:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/create-and-use-an-index-to-improve-performance-HA010210347.aspx

Comment: An index will speed up `TERM LIKE "cam%"` quite a lot, but not so much for searching anywhere in the string. Seems to me if you need to search for a string buried within a field when there are that many records, you likely have a design error somewhere.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton - Is Access/Jet smart enough to use the index to do an index scan as opposed to a table scan? If it is, then an index would help significantly, as it means you'd be loading just that one column worth of data to scan through instead of reading the whole table off the disk. It's still a scan and not a more efficient seek (as you're suggesting), but it's an improvement over a complete table scan, which is what you'd have with no index that covers that column.

Comment: It's smart enough to use the index if you're searching at the beginning, but I think it does a table scan otherwise. I'm not certain on that -- you could turn on JET SHOWPLAN and see for yourself what it does. But it seems to me that there's something wrong with the schmea design if you have 1 million records and need to search for a string buried within a field of those 1 million records.

Comment: Neither Jet or SQL server will use a normal index on that type of wildcard search.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 1,000,000 records, why aren't you using SQL Server? How much traffic is this application going to get? I wouldn't expect any site to scale with MS-Access as its data store.

Comment: Will SQL Server search faster? Or are you suggesting full-text indexing as an alternative once SQL Server was in place? Also, what do you mean by "site"? Did anybody say this database was behind a web server?

Comment: Thanks iKnowKungFoo.. this application is for one user. But the number of records are 1,000,000.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton yes SQL will be a lot quicker, especially if it is running on a serparate machine, we has a similar situation with doing like '*aspirin*' on a access database for a medical coding database if about 100,000 records, it went from 2mins to about 2 seconds ... and the conpany agreed to buy a SQL server after years of refusing

Comment: I think you're very optimistic in stating categorically that you can know for a fact that the SQL Server search will be faster. There are all sorts of reasons why it might not be.

Comment: @spacemonkeys: `LIKE 'aspirin'` is way different than `LIKE '%aspirin%'`